# Citreon C2 - Brake pedal only goes halfway when driving

Tags: brakes

I went up on the curb while reversing yesterday. I slowly moved away and everything seemed fine. However, now my brake pedal only goes down halfway and won't go to the floor.

Apart from this nothing seems to be wrong (no warning lights or OBD faults). I've looked online but I can't find anything that relates to this. Any ideas before I call the garage on Monday?

Comment: It sounds like your curb bump has re-adjusted the brakes properly! Maybe the auto-adjusters operated by the handbrake had got stuck before and the bump freed them so they are now working. I would be more worried about driving a car where the brake pedal *did* go down to the floor. Half way is about right in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After giving the car a 'once over' yesterday I think you're right. Brakes do feel a lot better now which is strange considering but can't complain.